# I need to switch to an old version of R to run one script

Tags: r, version

I am trying to run a script that was build on an older version of R.  It runs on one computer, which is running R/3.4.4. It breaks on another, running R/3.6.3.  The author has an issue checked out on his github to fix this (I think), but he's finishing his PhD so that could happen in two months, two years, or never.

I installed R/3.4.4 in my `$HOME/.local` path (the other is in `/usr/bin`). I just can't figure out how to temporarily point to the version in .local when I run this script.  I tried setting R_HOME with `export R_HOME=$HOME/.local` but R ignores that.

I am sure this has been asked before, but I can't find anything that doesn't involve RStudio.  I don't have RStudio on my WSL (running Ubuntu 20.04), so I need a terminal-based solution.

Can someone explain how to do this?  I feel really dense and really exhausted. Thank you.

Comment: Have you just run `$HOME/.local/bin/Rscript /path/to/file.R`? If you use the specific executable to use, it won't look in `/usr/bin/`. *However*, you do need the R-3.4 version of all packages you need: often they need to be installed "fresh" between minor versions of R (3.4 and 3.6 are different minor versions).

Comment: What exactly does your script look like? Does it just call `R` or `Rscript`? If that's the case your OS will search your system paths to find the program. You can see which one if finds by calling `which R` or `which Rscript`. If you want to change which one it finds, then you need to explicitly pass the full path, or change your path environment variable to list the folder where the R you want to run is listed before the one you don't want to use. `R_HOME` is meaningful after you start R, it doesn't control which R you run.

Comment: @r2evans, wow...truly amazing what sleep deprivation will do to a person.  If you write this as an answer I'll accept it.  It's different from the proposed solution, and a better fix for my temporary needs.  I'll use renv for the package versioning! Thank you!

Comment: @MrFlick, yes - same as r2evans - this was the (very simple!) solution I was looking for.  I have been working for 3 full days,12 hours per day...sometimes after a certain point the simplest solutions just are unreachable to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing your `PATH` might be useful in some ways, but since (I'm inferring) that you intend this to be the *exception*, then just running this with the full path to the executable should be sufficient. If your task is encapsulated in a script named `script.R`, then perhaps

```
$HOMD/.local/R_3.4.4/bin/x64/Rscript /path/to/script.R
```

should be sufficient.

This may bite you, though, depending on how the current R is installed. You said it's in `/usr/bin/`, which suggests that its library path might be something like this:

```bash
$ Rscript -e '.libPaths()'
[1] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"
[2] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"
[3] "/usr/lib/R/library"
```

(where `Rscript` here is the default/current version). Unfortunately, the packages in those directories are not stored as version-specific, so it is possible (even likely) that using a more-modern version of a package with R-3.4.4 will fail in some way.

Two strategies for preempting this possibility. The first works fine assuming that you have all packages for R-3.4.4 in a specific directory.

1. One way is to set `R_LIBS_USER` (env-var) for the command. This can be on the same command-line, or it can be controlled via some `.Renviron` file or similar:

   ```bash
   $ mkdir -p .local/R-3.4.4/library
   $ R_LIBS_USER=~/.local/R-3.4.4/library Rscript -e '.libPaths()'
   [1] "/home/r2/.local/R-3.4.4/library"
   [2] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"
   [3] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"
   [4] "/usr/lib/R/library"
   ```

   With this, assuming all packages needed are found in that first path, it will never look in the others, so there should be no conflicts experienced. If your script is stable/unchanging and you don't break your instance of R-3.4.4 within `.local`, then ... all is happy.
2. Modify the script itself to hard-control the library paths. By over-riding `R_HOME` (env var), you can override all of the defaults.

   ```bash
   echo "R_HOME=~/.local/R-3.4.4" > .Renviron # current working directory, regardless of script.R
   Rscript /path/to/script.R
   ```

   This assumes that `.local/R_3.4.4` is a *complete* R installation ... it needs all of the base stuff as well as any other packages you may have installed.

Answer (score 0):

You have possibly added to the path the new directory AFTER the old one. You can check this using:

```
echo $PATH
```

If it's the case then you need to add it IN FRONT OF the path. Assuming that you install it in `/usr/local/bin`, then you should use the following command:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```